# html-proof jekyll website with .html extension-less internal links

Tags: jekyll

I have created a static website using Jekyll and recently upgraded from Jekyll 2.5.3 to 3.1.1. Since Jekyll version 3 .html extensions  are dropped from internal links, which gives us nice urls. This I love.

Since all pages are still created using the html extension, verifying the site using [HTML Proofer](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer) now fails, because it detects dead links.
This breaks my continuous integration system (setup according to [jekyllrb ci docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/)) on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/serraict/serraict.github.io).

So, I love the .html-less links AND that html-proofer checks my internal links. But how do can I verify the .html-less links using html-proofer?

There is a [Jekyll talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/testing-jekyll-3-0-extension-less-urls-with-html-proofer/1896) on this subject; as well as a [Github PR](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer/pull/221). Neither helps me very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a new working PR for this in https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer/pull/311. You can use it like this until it gets merged:

Gemfile: `gem 'html-proofer', github: "Floppy/html-proofer", branch: "jekyll-3-extensionless-links"`

It adds a `assume_extension` option: `HTML::Proofer.new("./_site", assume_extension: ".html").run`

Or you can use the `--assume-extension=.html` command line switch if you're using the binary.

---

Edit: this was released and available in html-proofer 3.0.4 I'm currently using. The api is slightly different, `assume_extension` has become a switch, defaulting to false. So you'd do:

```
HTML::Proofer.new("./_site", assume_extension: true).run
```

or

```
htmlproofer ./Site --assume-extension
```

It works in combination with the extension options if you'd like a different extension for your pages than the default .html.

Comment: That seems to be just what I needed! Will check it out and report back here.

Comment: Thanks for the addition to html-proofer Floppy, nice work.